# The move_base isn't subscribing to /robot1/map

Tags: navigation, mapping, namespace, map-server, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hello everyone,**

*I'm trying to add a namespace to my robot. Firstly, I added* `_${arg robot_name}` *after all frames. I can control my different robots with* `rqt_robot_steering` *via their own control topics, for example, with this* `/robot1/mobile_base_controller/cmd_vel` *on `gazebo`. But I think that isn't important information,* **whatever**;

When I try to run amcl, `/robot1/move_base` doesn't subscribe to `/robot1/map`. I'm already remapping in `move_base` node:

```
    ...
    <param name="base_global_planner" type="string" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
    <rosparam file="$(find mrp2_navigation)/config/dwa_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <remap from="odom" to="odom_$(arg robot_name)" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg robot_name)/nav_vel" />
    <remap from="map" to="/$(arg robot_name)/map" /> 
</node>
```

And setting in `map_server`:

```
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" 
          args="$(find mrp2_navigation)/maps/milvus_repo.yaml" output="screen">
        <param name="frame_id" value="/$(arg robot_name)/map" />
    </node>
```

Also Here is `rqt_graph` output:

*(for newcomers to this website: right click image and say "**Open image in new tab**" for readable resolution)*

[image: image description]

**What should I set? Or What can I do?**

**Thanks in advance!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234620/the-move_base-isn%27t-subscribing-to-/robot1/map/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've removed remapping. And problem solved. Launching node in

```
<group ns="optimus_prime">
</group>
```

tag already remaps topics automatically.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ga_phantom](https://answers.ros.org/users/47311/ga_phantom/) on 2019-10-16**:
I got same problem with you, but I didn't add remapping in launch file, and move_base still not subscribe /robotx/map or /map. Do you have any idea of that. Thank you so much.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2019-10-16**:
run `roswtf` and look at which topics are listened instead of the wanted one. Or which topics are orphan

**Comment by [Ga_phantom](https://answers.ros.org/users/47311/ga_phantom/) on 2019-10-19**:
I solved the problem by change "/base_footprint" to "base_footprint" in local/global_costmap_params.yaml, Thks.